# Cgal quadratic programming objective function

Tags: c++, function, optimization, cgal, quadratic

I am trying to minimize a function like the following:

```
25*x^2 + 45*x*y + y^2
```

and similar constraints like:

```
(25 + y) + 25*x <= 1
```

in [CGAL::Quadratic_program](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/QP_solver/Chapter_main.html#Section_10.3).

To input "25x^2" and "y^2" in the objective function I can do the following:

```
qp.set_d(X, X, 50);
qp.set_d(Y, Y, 2);
```

but what about "45*x*y" ?

And how to add this constraint "(25 + y) + 25*x <= 1"
In my opinion like this, but i am not sure with 25:

```
qp.set_a(X, 0, 25);
qp.set_a(Y, 0, 1);
qp.set_b(0, 1);
```

One solution should be to update function to this form "y + 25*x <= -24"

```
qp.set_a(X, 0, 25);
qp.set_a(Y, 0, 1);
qp.set_b(0, -24);
```

(Please in constraint correct me if i am wrong)

I will be gratefull for any advices, expecially with "45*x*y" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with replacing "(25 + y) + 25*x <= 1" by "y + 25*x <= -24" is obviously correct.

For objective function try:

```
qp.set_d(X, Y, 90);
```

but your matrix D:

```
25     22.5
22.5    1
```

is not positive semidefinite, so the solver may fail.

Comment: I have used a bad example example (my apologies for that), namely, the sum of more equations of this shape:

    "(4*X + 3Y)^2 -> 16*X^2 + 24*X*Y + 9Y^2" etc,..

That is already positive semidefinite right? :]

Comment: Thanks pal, you help me so much, BTW: is there any way to get values of parameters in floating point and not in integer?

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it helped. Not sure how to change the solver's data type from `int`, but what about purely mathematical solution - reformulating the problem using scaling: x_new = x * 10^k for sufficiently large k, like x_new = x * 100000?..

Comment: I allready make it, but i have another problem, I dont know, how to get also negative values in parameters (only zero and greater, but thats not best solution if u understand), have you done something similar before?

Comment: There should be no problem with passing negative values

Comment: According to this "3a^2 + b^2 +2ab + a+ 6b + 2" in wolfram alpha, the values are (5/4, -17/4) but when i write it to code like this:


    `qp.set_d(0, 0, 6); 
    qp.set_d (1, 1, 2);
    qp.set_d(1, 0, 2);
    qp.set_c(0, 1);
    qp.set_c(1, 6); 
    qp.set_c0(2);`

and output is  0, 0

Comment: (BTW: looks that "2xy" is set_d(y, x, 2), because im getting better same results in another equation :])

Comment: That's interesting, they specify you should pass 2D matrix in the docs. Probably due to the goal function formulation 1/2<x, Dx> + <c, x>, where < , > is dot product.

Comment: O.K. thanks. And did you tried the formula above for result? Maybe im doing something wrong, could you give me right code to receive right results please? I mean to get the results above and not zeros. ;)

Comment: What about `qp.set_d(0, 0, 6); qp.set_d (1, 1, 2); qp.set_d(0, 1, 4); qp.set_c(0, 1); qp.set_c(1, 6);`? Also please try `qp.set_d(0, 0, 6); qp.set_d (1, 1, 2); qp.set_d(0, 1, 2); qp.set_d(1, 0, 2); qp.set_c(0, 1); qp.set_c(1, 6);`

Comment: First answer is right. ;-)
Definitely last question: Do you know how to extract only variable values?

Comment: @PavelSedlář what do you mean by extracting only variable values?

Comment: Normally, I am getting this:
```status: OPTIMAL
objective value: 8/1
variable values:
0: 2/1
1: 3/1```

and i want only variable values in for example, that form [4.2, 3.45878, 5.2365, etc.]

Comment: I would parse the output using perl/bash/awk in this case.

Comment: Hi man, its me again. Is there any posibility to setting up number of iterations for getting some results faster? Thanks,. ;)

Comment: Sorry haven't found anything like this

Comment: Ok, and have you know another optimization library for quadratic programming? When i have 3000 parameters + 9000 constraints, this takes too long time (6 hours in 340 iteration and would not stop)

Comment: There is some really good software on the market like Xpress, CPLEX, not sure about free version.

Comment: Hi, I have last two questions on you.

1. Program qp (CGAL::SMALLER, false, 0, false, 0); // SMALLER means to minimize function, or there is something, else? What happen when i change SMALLER to LARGER/GREATER
2. Is there chance to add starting points to parameters, from where could optimalization starts? like in pallas? https://github.com/latture/pallas-solver :)